# How can I trigger Geometry Nodes with the keyboard?

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm replicating PowerPoint with Geometry Nodes.

I have a "slide" integer input. As I increase the number, a camera moves along a line. I do that using a simulation zone. See, I want the timeline to be playing constantly so that elements can move in the presentation. So when the simulation zone sees a change in the "slide" input, it moves the camera to the right place.

Here's my challenge:
**I'd love to be able to trigger this using the keyboard like in regular PowerPoint.**

I've tried a couple of things:

- Make a GeoNodes node tool that increases an attribute when used. Problem is, you have to be in edit mode to use the tool, and it looks like my main simulation zone driving the camera rig won't update because of that.
- Make a script that increases the input by 1 when run. Again, doesn't seem like GeoNodes recognizes the change when it's playing.

If anyone has done anything like this, I'd love to hear the solution.
Thanks in advance!